# having an issue with AWS Gamelift fleet not activating with an Unreal Engine build

Tags: amazon-ec2, unreal-engine5, dedicated-server, amazon-gamelift

I am developing a dedicated game server on UE5.3 and plan on hosting it on AWS services. When I upload a build and create a fleet the fleet reaches the activating state and stops there.

the error code says SERVER_PROCESS_SDK_INITIALIZATION_TIMEOUT

according to my searches the error basically says there is either an issue with the executable path in the upload or my build has an issue in its code that prevents the call to initSdk().

However, I don’t think its either of the problems because I copied the code from the gamelift documentation. And I double checked the path.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem and what might be the solution?

here are some specifications of my environment:

- windows 11
- UE5.3 built from source
- GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-5.1.1
- GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-UnrealPlugin-5.1.0
- OpenSsl 3.2.1

Some of the things I tried:

- calling initSdk() instead of initSdk(serverParamerters)
- changing openSsl version to 1.1

nothing changes. I still get the timeout error.

I also tried running the server locally using Anywhere fleet and it works fine.